# Set an instance variable in my controller from the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance variable called @chosen_athlete in my controller. I use this variable to perform some calculations in the corresponding view. However the value of the @chosen_athlete variable should be settable by my currently logged in user. What is the proper way to set the @chosen_athlete variable and update the data in my view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a form

Take a look there : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't really answer my question. I know I need to use a form to do this, I'm just unclear on actually making the routing and submission work.